# How can I list Mapbox gridLayer elements that are in the user view?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'd like to list all of the elements from a Mapbox gridLayer that are visible to a user in the viewport.

There is an excellent example on the Mapbox site called '[Listing markers in view](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/listing-markers/)'. It shows all the markers on the featureLayer that are in the view of the browser.

I'd like to create something similar, but using using a gridLayer instead. (the gridLayer was created in TileMill)

Here is an example fiddle of the data with a version of non-working 'in-bounds' code:
http://jsfiddle.net/bfab/uSLVw/1/

For reference, the gridLayer has a variable in it (passed from TileMill in the UTFGrid) called '{{{Magnitude}}}' I'd like to list each of the instances of earthquakes that appear to the user, and add it to a list on the bottom left of the example. The function I'm trying to use is gridLayer.getData(latlng,callback).

Here is the snippet of code that is not working:

```
    map.on('move', function() {

        // Construct an empty list to fill with gridLayer elements.
        var inBounds = [],

        // Get the map bounds - the top-left and bottom-right locations.
        bounds = map.getBounds();

        // For each part of the grid, consider whether 
        // it is currently visible by comparing with the current map bounds.    
        // This is what fails....
        myGridLayer.getData(bounds,function(earthquake){
            inBounds.push(earthquake.Magnitude);
        });

        // Display a list of markers.
        document.getElementById('coordinates').innerHTML = inBounds.join('\n');
    });
```

Apologies if I am making a simple error...

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't (not easily at least)

1/ You misunderstand the getData function on the gridlayer

- first parm is not a boundary but a location latlng
- when you use this in a callback (onclick for example) you will get data only if you click on one of your circles, if not you get undefined). The data is not a list of markers but the information of your earthquake (e.g.  {DateTime: "2014-04-26T16:59:15.710+00:00", Magnitude: 3.9})

  ```
  myGridLayer.getData(event.latlng, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      // if clicked on a marker: data is defined 
      // e.g. Object {DateTime: "2014-04-26T16:59:15.710+00:00", Magnitude: 3.9} 
  });
  ```

http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/uSLVw/11/

2/ It is not easy to think in terms of markers when using gridlayer as the markers are already part of the image when you load tiles:

http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/bfab.i4nm0adm/3/0/2.png

The interaction is described in some javascript loaded at the same time

http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/bfab.i4nm0adm/3/0/2.grid.json